# Microsoft Access MySQL ODBC

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc, windows-11

I have installed the MySQL 8.1 Connector. I have updated MDAC. I have update the Visual C++ Redistributables. I can connect to the server, but cannot create a table link. I have tried this with the GUI and with VBA code. I get a similar error each time.

I am running Access (Office 365) on Windows 11.

[image: ODBC Connector showing success]

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

Wow! After hours of trying to find an answer to this I realized that my hosting service (InMotion) is using MariaDB even though the user interface for creating databases still says MySQL. So I downloaded the MariaDB connector and it works just fine. Wish I could get back the hours I spent on this. :(

Comment: FWIW, the MySQL Connector *can* connect to a MariaDB server. At least normally.

Comment: Hi Andre. In this experience I had, the I could connect to the server successfully (as you can see in my first screen grab), but I could not create the table link. I tried adjusting all sorts of options. I tried to create it with a DSN and with VBA DAO objects, but nothing worked.